# Why is the variable 'temp' reusable in this linked list code?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

In this code, the variable `temp` is reusable (in while loop) and can be used to allocate memory again and again without any error. Is it normal functioning?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int i;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *head,*temp;
    char c;
    printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);

    if((c=='Y')||(c=='y'))
    {
       head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       head->next=NULL;
       printf("Please enter your data: ");
       scanf(" %d",&head->i);
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    while((c=='Y')||(c=='y'))    //LOOK INTO THIS LOOP
    {
       temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       temp->next=head;
       printf("Please enter your data: ");
       scanf(" %d",&temp->i);
       head=temp;
       printf("Do you want to enter data? Y/N ");
       scanf(" %c",&c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure - because it's value is copied out to 'head' before it is overwritten.  The memory it points to is not leaked.  Such pointer reloading is often described as 'reseating'.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit But even after commenting the piece where 'temp' is copied into header, the code works fine.

Comment: @Gaurav : In what way does the code work fine?  The items will not be added to the list, and there is no reference retained to free the memory - the memory has "leaked" - the code will not crash as such (since there is user interaction in the loop you are hardly likely to exhaust the memory in any reasonable time), but that is not the same as "working fine".

Comment: @Clifford sorry, by fine I meant to say that it will not be throwing any error, but sure memory will be leaked.

Comment: @Gaurav : To throw and error would require that run-time should detect that an assignment to temp replaces a previous allocation (and not simply an unitialised value or valid pointer to non-heap memory), and that no reference has been retained elsewhere to that allocation.  That is too complex for the C run-time to spot.  Run-time memory management analysis tools such as Valgrind or some expensive and complex static-analysis tools may be used to spot such _semantic_ errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely normal, `temp` is not the memory allocated, it is simply a pointer to the allocated memory; that pointer-value can be copied to another pointer-variable and that pointer-variable may then be used to access the same allocated memory and also to later de-allocate it.  Moreover it does not matter how many times the pointer is copied, it is the pointer-value not the specific pointer-variable that is necessary for memory access and management.

The pointer value in `temp` is copied to `head` to add the item to the list; similarly before that, the previous `head` is copied to `head->next` to maintain the links.  Presumably elsewhere in the code when a entry is removed from the list, the value in `head` is used to un-link the head element and free the allocated memory; something like:

```
temp = head ;        // Copy current head pointer
head = head->next ;  // Remove head from the list
free(temp) ;         // Deallocate removde list item
```

Comment: Since it is the pointer not the memory itself, can that allocated memory be assigned a name?

Comment: Independently of the pointer? - Not really.  That is the difference between an _array_ and a _pointer-to_memory_.  In C++ you could wrap the allocation in an class and add `[]` operator overloading to access it like an array.  The object instance name would then syntactically at least refer to the memory (but note that C++'s various standard library container classes such as `std::vector` already provide that functionality.  If you were using those you would hardly be crating your own linked list - `std::list` already provides that.

Answer (score 0):

yes, your code is normal, since you are assigning 'temp' to 'head' pointer in while(), so that you will not lose your address and you can again use 'temp' for creating memory for new structure. If you have not assign 'temp' to 'head' then it will lead you to danger.because once you allocate memory for new structure 'temp' will point to that structure and previous structure address you will lose even if structure is there but you will not be able to find it.Same code you can optimize and write like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
        int i;
        struct node *next;
        }NODE;
int main()
{
        NODE *head=NULL;
        NODE *tmp;
        char c;
        do{
                tmp=malloc(sizeof(NODE));
                printf("enter the number\n");
                scanf("%d",&tmp->i);
                tmp->next=head;
                head=tmp;
                printf("Do you want to enter another number\n");
                scanf(" %c",&c);
        }
        while(c=='y' ||c=='Y');
        printf("entered numbers are \n");
        while(head)
        {
                printf("%d\t",head->i);
                head=head->next;
        }
}
```